# app crashes while assigning QVariant to QVariant

Tags: c++, qt4

When I call a following function it crashes

```
void RequestBuilder::setData(QVariant &data)
{
    this->data=data;
}
```

`data` contains a `QVariantMap` (`data`also contains value as a QVariantMap) in it. And `this->data` is also `QVariant`.

Here are some more details while calling the function.

```
QVariantMap in,out;
in["name"]="nik";
out["details"]=in;
out["other"]="something";
QVariant param=QVariant(out);
setData(param);
```

The above function works fine if I pass map which contains primitive data types

```
QVariantMap abc;
abc["name"]="nik";
QVariant var=QVariant(abc);
setData(var);
```

Is there a difference when `QVariantMap` contains Non-primitive values?

Comment: I feel like your being redundant and saying the same thing twice: "Here, data contains a QVariantMap(dataalso contains value as a QVariantMap) in it."

Comment: @JonathanMee I mean to say, a `QVariantMap` is passed to `data`. and that passed `QVariantMap` contains another `QVariantMap` in in its key Value pair.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. I have attempted to answer, but with your questions wording I'm not sure if I'm answering the right thing.

Comment: @JonathanMee I have edited the question please go through it.

Comment: Your code is fine. I suspect another bug. Specifically one with the way your `QVariantMap` is allocated/passed. If it's compact enough, maybe you could paste the actual code here?

Comment: @JonathanMee I got the problem in my code. there was some problem in object initialization. But thanks for your support. sorry for wasting your time bro.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a bad `QVariant&`.

A `QVariantMap` is not a `QVariant` nor can it be downcast to one because it does not inherit from a `QVariant`.

`QVariantMap` is a [`QMap<QString, QVariant>`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html#QVariantMap-typedef)

What you might have meant to do is:

```
QVariantMap abc;
abc["name"]="nik";
setdata(abc["name"]);
```

Comment: sorry for my language. but this is not my problem. I have wraped that QVariantMap in a QVariant before passing it to `setData()`. which you can see in edited question.